# What is a glow map and how do I use it?

Tags: texturing, materials

I downloaded a set of textures and one of the textures included was called a glow map. I looked all over the web to figure out what it was and can't find anything. How do I use the glow map? By which I mean, how do I connect it to the Principled Shader?

Comment: you probably need to plug it into the Rougness socket of the Principled

Comment: Glow, as in emission? Maybe to the emission socket of the Principled BSDF shader. Please [edit] your question and show an exaple image that shows the result you are after.

Comment: I think 3DS refers to 'Glow Maps' . If this is one of those, I would plug it into _Emission Strength_, if it is black and white, or _Emission_ (color) if it is color.